# Open application in windows phone by hold special button

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an application and I want to open it by hold some special button on the phone (ex : camera button, power button...). Do you have some ideas or example code to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it isn't possible. On Windows Phone 7, the only physical buttons you can subscribe to are the back button and the camera button, and it's only when your application is running. So you can't launch an application that way.